# Recursive functions within OCaml objects

Tags: oop, recursion, methods, ocaml

I am trying to figure out recursion for OCaml in the context of an object's method. I have tried the following code but can't seem to get it to compile.

```
class foo =
object (self)
 method loopTest =
  let rec doIt x =
   Printf.printf "%d\n" x;
   if x>1 then doIt (x+1)
end;;
```

How do I create a recursive function of this sort within a method?

Revised code:

```
class foo =
object (self)
 method loopTest =
  let rec doIt x =
   Printf.printf "%d\n" x;
   if x<10 then doIt (x+1) in doIt 0
end;;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You still need to call doIt in your loopTest method. `let` just defines doIt, just like `method` just defines a method, and does not call it. The compiler detects this because it doesn't know what to return from loopTest (like a method that does not have return type void, but has no implementation in C# or Java).

Also, you're in for an infinite loop with this code, maybe `if x>1 then doIt (x-1)` followed by `doIt 100` is a better idea.

Answer (score 2):

My OCaml is rusty, but I don't think let evaluates to what it bound. If you want testLoop to call doIt, tack on a in doIt or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Two infinite loops in the same code ;), you should learn about Iterators I guess;)